# Is there a best practice for organizing typescript files in an npm package?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing an npm package that will be used by a few people. This is the structure of my source code. As you can see I have one file called `types.ts` with type declarations per `index.ts` file. Does it look alright or is there some best practice for organizing the code differently?

I tried searching on this topic but came up blank.

```
/src
--/Client
----index.ts
----types.ts
--/Request
----index.ts
----types.ts
--index.ts
--types.ts
```

Comment: what is the framework you are going to use ,is it Angular?

Comment: @Heshan: I'm not using any framework. There is no UI. It will become an npm library.